# Is the Gudimallam lingam a testament to Shivling being phallic?

Tags: history, shiva-lingam, idols

The gudimallam lingam which dates anywhere around 1 BC to 2 AD is probably the oldest surviving shivling. This however is unmistakably phallic in nature. Does this prove that shivling is a penis after all? Or is there much more to the story, its interpretation and it s understanding?

Comment: Kindly elaborate on how it is "unmistakebly phallic".

Comment: @GarudadhvajaDaasa Here's a pic link of it https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Gudimallam_linga%2C_a_19th-century_replica_from_the_temple.jpg/220px-Gudimallam_linga%2C_a_19th-century_replica_from_the_temple.jpg.

search up the name and you'll get more pics of it

Comment: Officially no one wants to admit lingam-yoni is sexual in nature because humans focus too much on the sex on not enough on the meaning behind it, especially in Kali Yuga. In my opinion, lingam-yoni is representing the sexual union of Shiva-Shakti, not as Ardhanārīśvara, their unified form, but in Yab-Yum. In other words, all of reality comes from the interface between puruṣa & prakṛti. Lingam represents the consciousness of Saguṇa Brahman piercing through the māyā of prakṛti in order to enjoy līlā. Without their divine union, there is no space or time for jīva to exist.

Comment: However, because of the nature of Hinduism, others will have their own interpretations. Humans are easily distracted, especially by sex, so people would rather just not think about it that way. Which means you will get a lot of different opinions on here. Which is why the question is being voted on to close. Unfortunately, my personal understanding is based not just on reading, but on insights and revelations as well, so I cannot point you to a source for my answer, which is why it must be a comment.